# Can I use a USB connector/plug for RGB Led Strip

Tags: led, usb, dc, connector

So I have an RGB Led Strip that requires power (3 Colours and the ground).
In total it draws about 1A @ 12V = 12W.

Could a USB socket be used to handle this? Otherwise I'm simply seeking a neat and tidy (read small but with some grab still) connector to plug and unplug the unit from the controller. Perhaps even an S-Video connector? I'm sort of clueless but just want something to handle this relatively small load.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

USB is specified with a maximum of 2.5W (500mA @ 5V) and this is only after the devices exchanged this information and the software allows it.

If you're talking about the plug itself: It can probably handle the current but one day you'll plug it into your PC because you forget about that .. special .. USB plug and it might fry your internals. Do not use plugs for purposes other than they are intended for.

Go get some standard Molex connector which doesn't have a special "function". How do you plan to switch your LEDs on and off anyway?

Comment: Thanks. It's for a special setup between an arduino like setup with a darlington array driving them in PWM. Molex could work well, like the old IDEA power I believe.

Comment: So if you just require external power, you could also use a standard 2 pin power jack like found with many external wall wart type power supplies. Then you could hook up the bases of your darlington arrays using a standard molex connector or whatever you have onboard already.

Answer (score 0):

USB 2.0 Spec dictates 0.5W (5V @ 100mA) without enumeration, 2.5W with. Typically, you can find PCS that provide about 1 Amp or 5W regardless of enumeration.

Dedicated usb supplies may provide 10.2 Watts for iPad standard charging rate.

So no, your target is unrealistic. This is before we even get into switching regulator efficiency losses of 80%.